# Deploying and installing my own Eclipse plugin project with it's dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

I am developing a plugin project for Eclipse 2021 that will be used by our company only.
This is my first attempt at plugin development.

When I run the plugin in debug mode it works fine but I cannot figure out how to export the plugin correctly with it's dependencies.

When I try to install the exported plugin I get this error:

> Operation details
> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
> Software being installed: binding generator 1.0.0.202201041327 (com.ourcompany.bindingGenerator.plugin 1.0.0.202201041327)
> Missing requirement: binding generator 1.0.0.202201041327 (com.ourcompany.bindingGenerator.plugin 1.0.0.202201041327) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections 0.9.12' but it could not be found

I'm trying to find out how I can add the org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections 0.9.12 dependency to my exported jar?

I've added the org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections 0.9.12 library/plugin to the required Plug-Ins and Automated Management of Dependencies through the Dependencies tab of the plugin.xml but that's it right now...

[image: I've added the org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections 0.9.12 library/plugin to the required Plug-Ins and Automated Management of Dependencies through the Dependencies tab of the plugin.xml but that's it right now...]

I'd like to know how to add the missing bundle to my build through the plugin.xml if possible or any other means if not.

The missing bundle itself was added to the target platform definition file through Maven.

[image]

Comment: You can't add other plug-ins to your plug-in jar. You need to build an update site containing your plug-in and the dependencies. See for example [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks! I will look at the documentation, really appreciated.